# Hibernate with H2 doesn't store the data

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm developing a simple java app with Hibernate using H2.

I'm receiving no exception.
The Hibernate output and the trace file of H2 shows me an insert of the data.

But the data are not stored in the db.
Neither hibernate nor the H2 console shows any inserted data.

Maybe someone has an idea.

Thx

This my Hibernate config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/HibTest;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;FILE_LOCK=NO</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

    <mapping package="de.test.hib.domain" />
    <mapping class="de.test.hib.domain.Data" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my domain class:

```
package de.test.hib.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;


@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_DATA",name="SEQ_DATA_GEN",initialValue=1)
public class Data implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String content;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Data)) {
            return false;
        }

        Data other = (Data) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="SEQ_PERSON_GEN")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

And the persisting process:

```
Transaction trans = HibernateUtils.getInstance().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
HibernateUtils.getInstance().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(this);
HibernateUtils.getInstance().getCurrentSession().flush();
trans.commit();
```

Comment: Meanwhile I integrated Spring to manage the Hibernate connectivity. It works with this solution, but introduced a little overhead to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the option `FILE_LOCK=NO` from the database URL. It is very dangerous, as it means the database file is not protected. Opening the database that way will corrupt the database file if the database is already open.

Comment: I know. Because I had the H2 console open to check the content I startet with no lock. ;)

Comment: If you do that, it will most likely corrupt the database. Instead, I suggest to use the [automatic mixed mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode)